# MyBatis and Associations Performance

Tags: java, performance, orm, mybatis

I found this concept in MyBatis association model:

I have two tables: Person and Book, where each Person can have many Books,

```
@Select("SELECT * FROM person")
@Results(value = {
    @Result(property = "personId", id=true,column = "personId"),
    @Result(property="books",  column="personId",  javaType=ArrayList.class, many=@Many(select="getAllBooks")),
})
ArrayList<Person> getAllPersons ();


@Select("SELECT * FROM book where personId=#{personId}")
ArrayList<Book> getAllBooks(int personId);
```

So Imagine we have 1000 persons, it means this query will execute 1000 times:

```
@Select("SELECT * FROM book where personId=#{personId}")
```

The question is how (or if it is possible) to fetch all books in one query and map them to all person by using PK/FK. I believe it is happening in JPA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found N+1 problem in MyBatis Docs:

> While this approach is simple, it will not perform well for large data sets or lists. This problem is known as the "N+1 Selects Problem". In a nutshell, the N+1 selects problem is caused like this:

```
You execute a single SQL statement to retrieve a list of records (the "+1").
For each record returned, you execute a select statement to load details for each (the "N")
```

This is the link:
http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html